# Dynamically update JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS array like this.

```
const PaymentMethods = [
    {
      type: "DEBIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    },
    {
      type: "CREDIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    }
  ];
```

As you can see, I am hardcoding these right now. But I want to dynamically update this `PaymentMethods`

For e.g. There will be 2 checkbox. `isCredit` and `isDebit`

1. If `isCredit = true` and `isDebit = false`, I want the `PaymentMethods` to look like this

```
const PaymentMethods = [
    {
      type: "CREDIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    }
  ];
```

2. If `isCredit = false` and `isDebit = true`, our `PaymentMethods` should be

```
const PaymentMethods = [
    {
      type: "DEBIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    },
  ];
```

3. If `isCredit = false` and `isDebit = false`, our `PaymentMethods` should be

```
const PaymentMethods = [];
```

4. If `isCredit = true` and `isDebit = true`, our `PaymentMethods` should be like original one at top.

Can someone please highlight me how I can do this. I have searched quite a few but didn't find anything in this regard yet.

Comment: ```PaymentMethods.push({
      type: "CREDIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    })``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: First issue, you're defining your array as a `const` rather than a `let`.  Constants are not intended to change

Comment: @Qiniso depends on how you are going to use the array, using the Array methods doesn't require you to define the array as ```let```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `filter` for this purpose on `Array`. Just like below:

```js
const getPaymentMethods = (isCredit, isDebit) => {
  const paymentOptions = [
    {
      type: "DEBIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    },
    {
      type: "CREDIT",
      cardType: "VISA",
    }
  ];
  
  if (isCredit && isDebit) {
    return paymentOptions;
  } else if (isCredit) {
    return paymentOptions.filter(e => {return e.type === 'CREDIT'});
  } else if (isDebit) {
    return paymentOptions.filter(e => {return e.type === 'DEBIT'});
  }
  
  return [];
}

// test cases:
console.log(getPaymentMethods(true, true));
console.log(getPaymentMethods(false, false));
console.log(getPaymentMethods(true, false));
console.log(getPaymentMethods(false, true));


// usage:
// const PaymentMethods = getPaymentMethods(true, false);
```

Read further about `filter` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options for you:

You can have a master array with the two entries, and use `filter` to create a filtered version for a particular value of the `isCredit` and `isDebit` flags:

```
let paymentMethods = AllPaymentMethods.filter(({type}) => type === "CREDIT" && isCredit || type === "DEBIT" && isDebit);
```

Live Example:

```js
const AllPaymentMethods = [
    {
        type: "DEBIT",
        cardType: "VISA",
    },
    {
        type: "CREDIT",
        cardType: "VISA",
    }
];
const isCredit = Math.random() < 0.5;
const isDebit = Math.random() < 0.5;
let paymentMethods = AllPaymentMethods.filter(({type}) => type === "CREDIT" && isCredit || type === "DEBIT" && isDebit);
console.log(`isCredit: ${isCredit}, isDebit: ${isDebit}, paymentMethods = ${JSON.stringify(paymentMethods)}`);
```

```html
Run repeatedly to see different values of <code>isCredit</code> and <code>isDebit</code>.
```

Or you can have the separate entries and build the array with a pair of `if` statements:

```
const isDebit = Math.random() < 0.5;
const isCredit = Math.random() < 0.5;
let paymentMethods = [];
if (isCredit) {
    paymentMethods.push(creditOption);
}
if (isDebit) {
    paymentMethods.push(debitOption);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const debitOption =
{
    type: "DEBIT",
    cardType: "VISA",
};
const creditOption =
{
    type: "CREDIT",
    cardType: "VISA",
};

const isDebit = Math.random() < 0.5;
const isCredit = Math.random() < 0.5;
let paymentMethods = [];
if (isCredit) {
    paymentMethods.push(creditOption);
}
if (isDebit) {
    paymentMethods.push(debitOption);
}

console.log(`isCredit: ${isCredit}, isDebit: ${isDebit}, paymentMethods = ${JSON.stringify(paymentMethods)}`);
```

```html
Run repeatedly to see different values of <code>isCredit</code> and <code>isDebit</code>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this as a guid. not a fully functional code

```
  const PaymentMethods = [];
  let debitChecked = false; // varibles to keep checked status
  let creditChecked = false;

  onDebitCheckboxChanged() { // on check state change function
    this.debitChecked =   //TO DO get checkbox status
    this.updatePaymentMethods();
  }

  onCreditCheckboxChanged() { // on check state change function
    this.creditChecked =  //TO DO get checkbox status
    this.updatePaymentMethods();
  }

  updatePaymentMethods() { //update array acordingly
    this.PaymentMethods = [];
    if (debitChecked === true) {
      this.PaymentMethods.push({
        type: "DEBIT",
        cardType: "VISA",
      })
    }

    if (creditChecked === true) {
      this.PaymentMethods.push({
        type: "CREDIT",
        cardType: "VISA",
      })
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This vanilla Javascript solution.

Firstly for HTML code

```
<h2>Choose payments</h2>
<input type="checkbox" name="payment" value="CREDIT" checked> CREDIT<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="payment" value="DEBIT"> DEBIT<br>
<hr>
<button onclick="checkout()">checkout</button>
```

Secondly for Javascript code

```
var checkbox =  document.getElementsByTagName('input');

function checkout() {
  const AllPaymentMethods = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
      AllPaymentMethods.push({
        type: checkbox[i].value,
        cardType: "VISA"
      });
    }
  }

  console.log(AllPaymentMethods);
}
```

Also if you need to check it https://codepen.io/abhar/pen/ZEEomYj